# How to fix MySql Exception Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql, vb.net

Hello everyone...!
            on my Windows 7 PC I have installed XAMP yesterday for php programming, today I am running my asp.net2010 web project it giving the above exception `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`
 my vb.net2010 db is in MySQL, for that I use SQLyog Enterprise IDE for db management. Both XAMP and SQLyog Enterprise access port 3306 for MySQL server.
so how to fix following exception which is coming after running the my vb.net2010 application. Thanks in Advance.

```html
 MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Answer (score 0):

The default setting for XAMPP MySQL's root user is to have no password. Remove the password from whatever code is trying to connect to the DB and try again...